# phpnuke to wordpress script

Tags: wordpress

I'm searching for script that can transfer all my data from an old website build in phpnuke to the new one that will be build in wordpress, that includs, all users and pass, posts, etc,
Anybody how something? 
Thank you.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this script you can just convert postnuke articles into WordPress

Source : http://www.csamuel.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/pnconvert.txt

```
 <?php

/*
   pnconvert.php - a simple script to convert postnuke articles into WordPress
                   entries.
   Copyright 2004 Bryan Klingner (wares.b@overt.org)

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "FIXME";
    $password = "FIXME";

    $sourcedb = "FIXME"; // your postnuke database
    $sourcetable = "nuke_stories"; // your postnuke stories table
    $sourcecat = "nuke_topics"; // your postnuke topics table

    $destdb = "FIXME"; // your wordpress database
    $desttable_prefix = "FIXME"; // you word press table prefix

    $db_connect = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
                    or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($sourcedb, $db_connect);
    $srcresult = mysql_query("select * from $sourcetable", $db_connect) 
                    or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());

    $srccatresult = mysql_query("select * from $sourcecat", $db_connect)
                    or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());

    // sanitize function stolen from wordpress source
    // used to generate the dashed titles in the URLs
    function sanitize($title) {
        $title = strtolower($title);
        $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
        $title = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title);
        $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
        $title = trim($title, '-');

        return $title;
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert postnuke stories and comments to WordPress</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Convert postnuke stories and comments to WordPress</h1>
<hr>
<?php
    if($submit)
    {
        echo "<p>Converting Postnuke to WP2 databases!</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>This is a preview of what is going to happen,
            to actually convert you'll need to press the
            button at the very bottom of this page!</p>";
    }
?>

<hr>
<h2>Category Conversions</h2>

<?php
    // copy over categories
    $rownum = 0;
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($srccatresult))
    {
        $mytopictext = mysql_escape_string($myrow['pn_topictext']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $desttable_prefix . "categories`
               (
                 `cat_ID`,
                 `cat_name`,
                 `category_nicename`,
                 `category_description`
               )
               VALUES
               (
                 '$myrow[pn_topicid]',
                 '$myrow[pn_topicname]',
                 '$mytopictext',
                 '$mytopictext'
               );";
        print $sql;
    echo "<br />";
    if ($submit && ( $myrow[pn_topicid] > 1 ) )
        {
            mysql_select_db($destdb, $db_connect);
            mysql_query($sql, $db_connect) or die("Fatal error: ".mysql_error());
        }


    }

?>
<hr>
<h2>Story Conversion</h2>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
    <thead>
        <td>pn_sid</td>
        <td>pn_title</td>
        <td>pn_time</td>
        <td>pn_hometext</td>
        <td>pn_bodytext</td>
        <td>pn_topic</td>
        <td>pn_counter</td>
        <td>comments</td>
    </thead>
<?php
    $rownum = 0; 
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($srcresult))
    {

        $myhometext = mysql_escape_string($myrow['pn_hometext']);
    if($myrow['pn_bodytext'])
    {
            $mybodytext = mysql_escape_string($myrow['pn_bodytext']);
        $myhometext = $myhometext.'\n<!--more-->\n'.$mybodytext;
        #$myhometext = $mybodytext;
    }

        $mytitle = mysql_escape_string($myrow['pn_title']);
        $myname = mysql_escape_string(sanitize($mytitle));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $desttable_prefix . "posts` 
               ( 
                 `ID` ,
                 `post_author` ,
                 `post_date` ,
                 `post_date_gmt` ,
                 `post_content` ,
                 `post_title` ,
                 `post_name` ,
                 `post_category` ,
                 `post_excerpt` ,
                 `post_status` ,
                 `comment_status` ,
                 `ping_status` ,
                 `post_password` ,
                 `to_ping` ,
                 `pinged` ,
                 `post_modified` ,
                 `post_modified_gmt` ,
                 `post_content_filtered` ,
                 `post_parent` ) 
               VALUES 
               ( 
                 '$myrow[pn_sid]',
                 '1',
                 '$myrow[pn_time]',
                 '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                 '$myhometext',
                 '$mytitle',
                 '$myname',
                 '$myrow[pn_topic]',
                 '',
                 'publish',
                 'open',
                 'open',
                 '',
                 '',
                 '',
                 '$myrow[pn_time]',
                 '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                 '',
                 '0' );";

        // only really do insert if requested
        if ($submit)
        {
            mysql_select_db($destdb, $db_connect);
            mysql_query($sql, $db_connect);

            // now get the ID of the post we just added
            $sql = "select MAX(ID) from " . $desttable_prefix . "posts";
            $getID = mysql_query($sql, $db_connect);
            $currentID = mysql_fetch_array($getID);
            $currentID = $currentID['MAX(ID)'];
            printf("<h2>Just inserted ID %s</h2>\n", $currentID);

            // add post2cat map... why does he have this table?
            if ($myrow['pn_topic'] == 0)
                $topicnum = 1;
            else
                $topicnum = $myrow['pn_topic'];
            $sql = "insert into `" . $desttable_prefix . "post2cat` (`post_id`, `category_id`) VALUES ('$currentID', '$topicnum');";
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $db_connect) or die("Fatal error: ".mysql_error());
        }

        // print out source information
        if ($rownum++ % 2 == 0)
            printf("<tr bgcolor=\"#BBBBBB\">");
        else
            printf("<tr>\n");
        printf("    <td>%s</td>\n
                    <td>%s</td>\n
                    <td>%s</td>\n
                    <td>%s</td>\n
                    <td>%s</td>\n
                    <td>%s</td>\n
                    <td>%s</td>\n", 
                $myrow["pn_sid"], 
                $myrow["pn_title"], 
                $myrow["pn_time"], 
        $myrow["pn_hometext"], 
        $myrow["pn_bodytext"], 
                $myrow["pn_topic"], 
                $myrow["pn_counter"]);

        // retreive all associated comments
        $mysid = $myrow["pn_sid"];
        mysql_select_db($sourcedb, $db_connect);
        $comments = mysql_query("select * from nuke_comments where pn_sid = $mysid", $db_connect);
        print "<td>";
        print "<table cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"3\" bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">";
        print "<thead>";
        print "    <td>pn_tid</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_sid</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_date</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_name</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_email</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_url</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_host_name</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_subject</td>";
        print "    <td>pn_comment</td>";
        print "</thead>";

        $comrownum = 0;
        while ($comrow = mysql_fetch_array($comments))
        {

            $myname = mysql_escape_string($comrow['pn_name']);
            $myemail = mysql_escape_string($comrow['pn_email']);
            $myurl = mysql_escape_string($comrow['pn_url']);
            $myIP = mysql_escape_string($comrow['pn_host_name']);
            $mycomment = mysql_escape_string($comrow['pn_comment']);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $desttable_prefix . "comments` 
                     ( 
                        `comment_ID` , 
                        `comment_post_ID` , 
                        `comment_author` , 
                        `comment_author_email` , 
                        `comment_author_url` , 
                        `comment_author_IP` , 
                        `comment_date` , 
                        `comment_date_gmt` , 
                        `comment_content` , 
                        `comment_karma` , 
                        `comment_approved` , 
                        `user_id` )
                     VALUES 
                     (
                        '',
                        '$currentID',
                        '$myname',
                        '$myemail',
                        '$myurl',
                        '$myIP',
                        '$comrow[pn_date]',
                        '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                        '$mycomment',
                        '0',
                        '1',
                        '0'
                     );";

            if ($submit)
            {
                mysql_select_db($destdb, $db_connect);
                mysql_query($sql, $db_connect)
                    or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());
            }


            if ($comrownum++ %2 == 0)
                print "<tr bgcolor=\"#BBBBBB\">";
            else
                print "<tr bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">";
            printf("    <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td></tr>\n",
                   $comrow["pn_tid"],
                   $comrow["pn_sid"],
                   $comrow["pn_date"],
                   $comrow["pn_name"],
                   $comrow["pn_email"],
                   $comrow["pn_url"],
                   $comrow["pn_host_name"],
                   $comrow["pn_subject"],
                   $comrow["pn_comment"]);

        }
        print "</table>\n";
        print "</td>\n";
        print "</tr>\n";
    }

?>
</table>

<hr>

<h2>Updating Comment Counts</h2>
<table><tr><th>SID</th><th>Comment count</th></tr>
<?php
    mysql_select_db($destdb, $db_connect);
    $tidyresult = mysql_query("select * from $desttable_prefix" . "posts", $db_connect)
                    or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());

    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($tidyresult))
    {
        $mypostid=$myrow['ID'];
        $countsql="select COUNT(*) from $desttable_prefix" . "comments"
             . " WHERE `comment_post_ID` = " . $mypostid;
        $countresult=mysql_query($countsql) or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());
        $commentcount=mysql_result($countresult,0,0);
        $countsql="UPDATE `" . $desttable_prefix . "posts`
            SET `comment_count` = '" . $commentcount .
            "' WHERE `ID` = " . $mypostid . " LIMIT 1";
        if($submit)
        {
            $countresult=mysql_query($countsql) or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());
        }
        if($commentcount > 0)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$mypostid</td><td>$commentcount</tr></tr>\n";
        }
    }
?>
</table>

<hr>

<h2>Updating Category Counts</h2>
<table><tr><th>Category</th><th>Category count</th></tr>
<?php
    mysql_select_db($destdb, $db_connect);
    $tidyresult = mysql_query("select * from $desttable_prefix" . "categories", $db_connect)
                    or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());

    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($tidyresult))
    {
        $mypostid=$myrow['cat_ID'];
        $countsql="select COUNT(*) from $desttable_prefix" . "post2cat"
             . " WHERE `category_id` = " . $mypostid;
        $countresult=mysql_query($countsql) or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());
        $commentcount=mysql_result($countresult,0,0);
        $countsql="UPDATE `" . $desttable_prefix . "categories`
            SET `category_count` = '" . $commentcount .
            "' WHERE `cat_ID` = " . $mypostid . " LIMIT 1";
        if($submit)
        {
          $countresult=mysql_query($countsql) or die("Fatal Error: ".mysql_error());
        }
        if($commentcount > 0)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$mypostid</td><td>$commentcount</tr></tr>\n";
        }
    }
?>
</table>

<hr>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert PN to Wordpress">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer man, but i had to convert posts, categories, users. I coudn't find anything on this, xoops documentation is very poor. So i did it with gConverter guys, they didi the job very  well.